# Creating reminder whenever task is half way through

Tags: tasks

I have a requirement where i need to create a reminder for every half way through the task.  Eg, if i have a task on 2 months from now, i need to create a reminder before 1 month, one reminder before 2 weeks, one reminder before 1 week, one reminder before 3 days and a finally on that day.

I think i have 2 options for this

1. A batch apex that runs everyday, checks and sends a reminder.
2. Time based workflow.

Please suggest.